# JSTL Session Lookup - Key Has Periods

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am working with some legacy code, and at some point there is a key in the session that is something like

```
session.setAttribute("com.org.something.Object",someObject);
```

Now trying to access this in a jsp using jstl is a bit difficult becuase if I tried it like I normally would I would do:

```
${sessionScope.com.org.something.Object.someFieldGetter}
```

As most of us can imagine it will fail because there is no com object in session scope.  I also tried

```
${sessionScope.'com.org.something.Object'.someFieldGetter}
```

And a parsing error was thrown.

Does anyone know how to resolve this so that I can correctly get the object similar to `session.getAttribute("com.org.something.Object")` but through jstl?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use square bracket syntax.

`${sessionScope['com.org.something.Object'].someFieldGetter}` should do it.